# Python ignores a certain functions write properties

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, file, printing

I have created a python script with 4 functions called:

```
create_dir()
create_list()
create_logic()
create_email()
```

I am able to run **each** script **separately** with a batch file like below:

```
REM:: Start.bat

@echo off
c:\python27\python create_dir.py
SLEEP 1
c:\python27\python create_list.py
SLEEP 1
c:\python27\python create_logic.py
SLEEP 1
c:\python27\python create_email.py
pause
```

Now I create 1 python script with each previous script as a function.

The problem is with the `create_logic()` function. When I call the scripts from
 `if __name__ == '__main__':` the `create_logic()` function does not create the file `non_existing.txt` and write to the file. **However** all the other scripts do their jobs..

Infact it looks like the program just skips the lines telling the script to create the file and write to it.

Below is the problem part. `non_existing.txt` does not get created in the script and i don't know why, any advice or explanations will be greatly appreciated.

```
#print the non matching lines   
f1=open('non_existing.txt', 'a')
f1.write('This ' + nomatch + ' does not exist in the list' +'\n')
f1.close()
```

complete script below:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch
import sys
import datetime
import time
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def create_dir():

    root = 'C:\\Users\\foo\\bar1'
    pattern = '*.jpg'
    #print all .jpg to fileX.txt
    with open('fileX.txt', 'w') as a:
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
           for filename in files:
                if fnmatch(filename,pattern):
                    a.write(str(os.path.join(filename)) + '\n')

def create_list():

    tm = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    file_prefix = 'fileY'
    #future use...
    #sys.stdout = open(file_prefix+now.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')+'.txt', "w")
    sys.stdout = open(file_prefix + '.txt', 'w')
    textprefix = ''
    textsuffix =  '_' + tm
    counter = 1
    #fill in range
    myRange = range(0,100)
    for count in myRange:
    #fill in abount of zeroes
        print textprefix + str(counter).zfill(5) + textsuffix
        counter += 1

def create_logic():
    #load lines from file into lists
    lines1 = [line1.rstrip('\n') for line1 in open('fileX.txt')]
    lines2 = [line2.rstrip('\n') for line2 in open('fileY.txt')]
    #set lines
    set_of_lines1 = set(lines1)
    set_of_lines2 = set(lines2)
    #set common
    common = set_of_lines1 & set_of_lines2
    #return lines which partially match as variable e
    partial_match = [e for e in lines1 if e.startswith(tuple(lines2))]
    matches = []
    for prefix in lines2:
        for snap in lines1:
            if snap.startswith(prefix):
                matches.append(prefix)
    #minus partially matched lines from fileY.txt
    for nomatch in set(lines2) - set(matches):
    #print the non matching lines   
        f1=open('non_existing.txt', 'a')
        f1.write('This ' + nomatch + ' does not exist in the list' +'\n')
        f1.close() 


def create_email():
    #date time settings
    Timt = time.strftime(' %H:%M')
    Datet = time.strftime('%A, %d_%B_%Y')  
    #address
    fromaddr = 'test@test.com'
    toaddr = 'test@test.com'
    #message 
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = 'non existing'
    body = 'Attached is non_existing. Sent on the ' + Datet + Timt
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    #attachement 
    filename = 'non_existing.txt'
    attachment = open('C:\\Users\\foo\\bar\\attachment_folder\\non_existing.txt', 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= %s' % filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    #server details
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, 'p@$$word')
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_dir()
    create_list()
    create_logic()
    create_email()
```

Comment: Presumably, `set(lines2) - set(matches)` results in an empty set so the for loop does not run.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks what could I do to prove this point can I make 1 variable and see if it prints? like `for nomatch in set(lines2):`

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not get created when the for loop doesn't run (i.e. `set(lines2)-set(matches)` is empty). If you want the file to be created in any case (even if it is empty after your function) you can do:

```
f1=open('non_existing.txt', 'a')
for nomatch in set(lines2) - set(matches):
#print the non matching lines   
    f1.write('This ' + nomatch + ' does not exist in the list' +'\n')
f1.close()
```

These are the `lines1` in the text file fileX.txt.

```
00001_20180218_061738.jpg
00002_20180218_061749.jpg
00003_20180218_061751.jpg
00005_20180218_061752.jpg
```

These are the `lines2` in the text file fileY.txt.

```
00001_20180218
00002_20180218
00003_20180218
00004_20180218
00005_20180218
```

they are then set in this format:

lines1:

```
lines1 = set('00001_20180218_061738.jpg', '00002_20180218_061749.jpg', '00003_20180218_061751.jpg', '00005_20180218_061752.jpg')
```

lines2:

```
lines2 = set('00001_20180218', '00002_20180218', '00003_20180218', '00004_20180218', '00005_20180218')
```

nomatch =

```
'00004_20180218'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i'm still trying to understand why `set(lines2) - set(matches)` results in an empty set.. will you be able to give an explanation?

Comment: @MALKAVIAN can you print lines2 and lines1? So I can see what is in them?